# Playing frame to frame animationClip

Tags: three.js

I'm using this code for playing animation for my collada model, but it has different actions all merged into one single `actionClip`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
    action = mixer.clipAction(animations[0]).play();
}
```

Is it possible to control the `animations[0]` starting frame and ending frame?